# How to get multiple elements from an Array?

Tags: discord.js

I'm using discord.js and I want to create a "server" with passcode. I want the passcode to be 6 letters long, so far I can only do one.
It has to be random as well. Like "ZSHWJK" Instead of "AAAAAA"

Code:

```
var serverPasscode = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

module.exports = {
    name: "createserver",
    description: "Creates a server",
    run(message, args, client){
        const newServer = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${message.author.name}'s server`)
        .setFooter(`${serverPasscode[Math.floor(Math.random() * serverPasscode.length)]}`)

        message.channel.send(newServer);
    }
};
```

Right now this can only return one element which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`for`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) loop and create a function such as this:

```js
function makeGuildPassword(length) {
  var result = ''; // create empty string that you will add random characters to
  var characters = // list of characters (you can change this however you want)
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'; 
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) { // create a loop
    // add a random character to the string; restart the loop
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(makeGuildPassword(6))
```